# How to restrict admin access based on Role Created with IP?

Tags: admin, user-roles, permissions, user, .htaccess

I have created 2 separate roles under Permission -> Roles.

**1).** For Employees
**2).** For Suppliers

I was wondering how to restrict **Role: Employees** to access admin area only from **specific IP**. We have static IP, which I believe would make this thing easier for us to restrict the admin access.

**Or**

Is there any other way to restrict some users from accessing admin area by IP only.

Please suggest if this is possible or not.

Thank you

Comment: anyone who could share their thoughts, perhaps someone encounter similar situation?

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is listen to the event `admin_user_authenticate_after` and check the ip if it matches.

This event is fired when a user is authenticated in the admin login process. It has the result passed in so you should be able to check the ip and if you want to limit the access simply set the result to false and thus the authentication will fail.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_user_authenticate_after', array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'user'     => $this,
    'result'   => $result,
));
```

*A bit of a thought though sometimes people may want to do a bit of work from home and in this case they would not be able to use the site.*